# Artificially slow down time

Tags: java, time

So in my game I have:

```
seconds = ((elapsed  - now) / 1.0E9F);
```

Where `elapsed` and `now` are `System.nanoTime();` called at different places in the code.

Then I convert this into a string and show it to the users. Based off of this code, I also have a countdown.

I want to slow down this countdown on occasion but I can't conceptualize how I'd do that.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: How is your countdown code working?

Comment: @Oli  I just subtract the seconds you're counting down from by the seconds I have in the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not Java, but might help you as anyways C# syntax ain't much different from java :P

http://blog.gallusgames.com/programming/a-custom-game-clock-in-csharp

Comment: I saw that you multiply the time by the scale factor. I tried this, and it worked, but it only sped up the time. I tried turning the scale factor to negative, but it still only sped up the time. How can I do the opposite, and slow down time?

Comment: Okay, I got it. I turned the scale factor to `0.XXF` instead of `-X.0F`. This was what I wanted. Now I get into the problem of having my total amount of seconds drop, in addition to it slowing down.

Answer (score 1):

You should introduce an interface like `Clock` that has a `nanoTime` method. Have one implementation that simply wraps the system clock, another that allows you to set the time to some arbitrary time. Pass whatever instance you need into the countdown code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should refer to System.nanoTime() in one place and one place only. During testing you can intercept the timing calls in this one place. Now you can tick once per 10 real ticks, or set time to an arbitrary value and re-set it during tests, etc.

Comment: I do not understand where this "one place" would be, and how to "intercept" them, and how to "tick once per 10 real ticks". Please explain